# The meaning of the phrase 'sou janai' (romaji)

Tags: phrases

What does the phrase 'sou janai' (romaji) mean in an informal speaking context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'That's not so', 'no', 'you're wrong', &c. By the way, it's 'Rōmaji' (no N), not 'romanji'.

Comment: Editted, thanks. If the suffix 'ne' is added to the end what it would mean?

Comment: Something like 'that's not true, is it?' It would depend on the context.

Comment: Now I see. I heard some people expressing their surprise with this phrase.